# Faster eigenvector routine for non-symmetric matrices with real eigensystem?

Tags: eigenvalues, lapack

I have non-symmetric real-valued matrices with real-valued eigensystems. How to compute eigenvectors efficiently?

Using `scipy.linalg.eig` (which calls `dgeev`) is 3-4 times slower than `scipy.linalg.eigh` (=>`dsyevd`) and 2x slower than `scipy.linalg.svd` (=>`gesdd`), but neither SVD nor hermitian eigenvalue decomposition are appropriate here. I'm guessing the need to support complex valued storage is responsible for extra overhead. Is there a faster routine to use for matrices which have real-valued eigenvalue decomposition?

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but these matrices are obtained from blocks of a covariance matrix like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3906484/showing-that-c-1bc-1bac-1-1-has-real-eigenvalues)

Comment: You might try finding the real Schur decomposition of your matrix and looking to the diagonal for the eigenvalues, but I'm afraid that you'll find apparent complex eigenvalues (showing up as 2x2 blocks) due to round-off error. This would avoid storing complex matrices, but might not be any faster.

Comment: Indeed, `scipy.linalg.schur` seems to be similar speed to `scipy.linalg.eig`

Comment: Note that Schur decomposition routines can produce a complex or real result (In MATLAB, schur(A,'real') vs. schur(A,'complex')  Using the 'real" option might make it a bit faster.

Comment: The scipy routine has an option "output='real'" to do the real Schur decomposition.

Comment: Are both the eigenvalues and eigenvectors real? I highly doubt you will find an off the shelf code which performs better than dgeev. But you might be able to write a specialized code depending on your specific matrix

Comment: @vibe yes, both eigenvalues and eigenvectors are real

Comment: @BrianBorchers I think that's exactly what `dgeev` does internally, so I am not surprised to see that they have the same speed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is trying to find out *why* that matrix has real eigenvalues in the first place. Usually it is because a suitable set of conjugations turns it into a symmetric matrix, and then you can reduce to a symmetric computation.

Multiplying and dividing by $(AC)^{-1}$ you can rewrite
$$
D_1 = C^{-1}BAC (C^{-1}BAC+I)^{-1},
$$
so your computation is equivalent to finding the eigenvalues $\mu_i$ of $M = C^{-1}BAC$ and then computing $\lambda_i = \frac{\mu_i}{\mu_i + 1}$ for each of them. Clearly the eigenvalues of $M$ are equal to those of $BA$. If $A=LL^T$ is a Cholesky factorization then those are equal to the eigenvalues of $L^TBL$, which is symmetric. Bingo.

For eigenvectors, the same computation shows that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $L^TBL$ then $(L^TC)^{-1}v$ is an eigenvector of $M$, and hence of $D_1$.

EDIT: oops, one does need an inverse in the last part.

Comment: thanks, nice trick! Cholesky was 10x faster than eigh and inverse 5x, so this reduction pays off in computation time

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov You make a call to `chol` *and* one to `eigh` with this solution.